# Spring 3, reference .xml from dependency

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies

I have 2 projects:

- Project **A**, a .war
- Project **B**, a .jar

I'm using **B** as a dependency in **A** through maven.

However, I want to load .xml files in **B** from **A**'s applicationContext.xml

Is this even possible and if so, how would I address them? classpath:/name_of_xml_in_B.xml does not seem to do the trick.

If any more information is needed, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to include it as `classpath:file_name.xml`. Just make sure it's present in the jar generated from project B - in this case in its root.